# How to disable fauxton interface?

Tags: couchdb, fauxton

How to disable fauxton interface in couchdb? I'd like to make `/_utils` endpoint to be treated like a normal endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to make `_utils` be treated like a "normal" endpoint, since all endpoints that begin with `_` are never normal. But you can disable it, and then it will be at least treated like a "normal" system endpoint.

From [this source](https://www.ionos.com/community/hosting/couchdb/4-steps-to-improve-your-couchdb-security/), (which talks about Futon--the `_utils` interface before CouchDB 2.x, but the same should work), simply comment-out the `_utils` line in your CouchDB `default.ini` file.